# Iterative fixed-point call of a function with a start value and defined number of calls

Tags: r, functional-programming

I'd like to write a simple and elegant function that applies a given function *f* to itself *n* times given some start value *x0*. It's not necessary a numerical function (e.g. *dirname*).

This solution solves the problem, but it looks too complicated:

```
it_call <- function(f, x0, n) Reduce(function(x, y) ifelse(x==1, f(x0), f(x)), 1:(n+1))
```

Example:

```
it_call(dirname, "/a/b/c/d/e", 3)

[1] "/a/b"
```

Another example:

```
i_call(sqrt, 256, 3)

[1] 2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This would work:

```
it_call <- function(f, x0, n) Reduce(function(x, y) f(x), 1:n, init=x0)
```

Not sure exactly what your criteria for "too complicated" is.

Comment: thx, it's definitely an improvement, looks much better now. Let's see if someone comes with solution that avoids  "reducing".

Comment: What exactly are you expecting in it's place? A different function name?

Comment: a different principle rather than reducing, don't know what. Maybe, reducing is the best option here.